# IPC using UNIX stream sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix, ipc

I have a beamforming and signal processing system where 3 different independent processes can started separately and are needed to send data blocks of 8MB to each other every few millisecs. I have used UNIX stream sockets for the IPC in these processes.I make the receiver of the block as the socket server and the sender as a client. Every time the sender has data to send, it connects to the server,puts the data on the socket and disconnects. This works perfectly, however since the sender is sending data at a very high frequency, I get a lot of errors from "connect()" function of the socket as "No such file or directory". I am guessing this happening because the socket has not yet been freed up from the last transmission.

Client Function:

```
int sockDAQ, len,respServer;
struct sockaddr_un remote;
int dispConStatus;



        for( j=0;j<16;j++){    

        if ((sockDAQ = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
            perror("socket");
        remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        switch(*(daqNum))
        {
            case DAQ1 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ1_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ2 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ2_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ3 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ3_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ4 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ4_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ5 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ5_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ6 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ6_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ7 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ7_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ8 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ8_PATH);
                        break;

        } 

len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);    
dispConStatus = connect(sockDAQ, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len);
        if ( dispConStatus != -1) {
            //printf("beamformer process found by %d.. Transferring packet\n",*(daqNum));     
            //printf("j : %d\n", j);
            respServer = NOT_TERMINATE;
            if ((send(sockDAQ, &respServer, sizeof(int), 0))==-1) perror("send");
            if ((send(sockDAQ, &transfer_bytes, sizeof(int), 0))==-1) perror("send");
            if ((send(sockDAQ, buf_1, transfer_bytes, 0))==-1) perror("send");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&bfmutex);
            printf("PACKETS TRANSFERRED %d FROM DAQ %d\n",++sentCount,*(daqNum));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&bfmutex);

            }
        else
            printf("FAILED TO FIND BF FOR DAQ %d\n",*(daqNum));

        }
```

If I try something like, I connect to the sever once and then I keep sending packets, it doesnot seem to work after the first transmission as "connect()" function returns -1 everytime.

Updated function :

```
int sockDAQ, len,respServer;
struct sockaddr_un remote;
int dispConStatus;

if ((sockDAQ = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
            perror("socket");
remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        switch(*(daqNum))
        {
            case DAQ1 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ1_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ2 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ2_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ3 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ3_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ4 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ4_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ5 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ5_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ6 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ6_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ7 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ7_PATH);
                        break;
            case DAQ8 : strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCKET_DAQ8_PATH);
                        break;

        } 

len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);    
dispConStatus = connect(sockDAQ, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len);



        if ( dispConStatus != -1) {

            respServer = NOT_TERMINATE;
            if ((send(sockDAQ, &respServer, sizeof(int), 0))==-1) perror("send");
            if ((send(sockDAQ, &transfer_bytes, sizeof(int), 0))==-1) perror("send");
            if ((send(sockDAQ, buf_1, transfer_bytes, 0))==-1) perror("send");

            pthread_mutex_lock(&bfmutex);
            printf("PACKETS TRANSFERRED %d FROM DAQ %d\n",++sentCount,*(daqNum));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&bfmutex);

            usleep(5000);

            respServer = NOT_TERMINATE;
            if ((send(sockDAQ, &respServer, sizeof(int), 0))==-1) perror("send");
            if ((send(sockDAQ, &transfer_bytes, sizeof(int), 0))==-1) perror("send");
            if ((send(sockDAQ, buf_1, transfer_bytes, 0))==-1) perror("send");

            pthread_mutex_lock(&bfmutex);
            printf("PACKETS TRANSFERRED %d FROM DAQ %d\n",++sentCount,*(daqNum));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&bfmutex);

            }

        close(sockDAQ);
```

This returns an error on the send() function:

```
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c: No such file or directory.
```

My questions are :

1. Do I need to terminate the connection and reconnect everytime I need to send a packet to a socket.
2. Is there a way to maintain the socket connection indefinetly as the constant connection and reconnection causes a lot of latency in my system and I am dropping packets over the sockets.
3. About the connect() function returning "No such file or directory" error, am I right to assume that this happening because the kernel has not freed up the socket from the last connection before I make the new one or am I missing something.

Help would me much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should keep the connection open. So open it at beginning of program, and close it only at the end.

Comment: The second code is doing the same, it opens the connection and sends 2 packets and then closes the connection, however it doesnt work as the 2nd packets dont go out and i get the error :
    ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you do not need to close the socket, you can maintain it open. Note that this might significantly change the logic of your server. You will need to maintain a socket pool that includes the listening socket and one socket per client. Then you have two architectural choices:

   - Either you run one thread per socket.
   - Or you run `select` or `poll` on the socket pool to decide what to do next. Libraries such as libev may make your life easier. Check out the [following example](http://codefundas.blogspot.se/2010/09/create-tcp-echo-server-using-libev.html).
2. Yes. Only `connect` when your clients starts and call `close` only when your client exits.
3. I assume this error occurs because you need to keep `accept`-ing connections. Depending on how you programmed your server, it may be busy handling a different client, instead of accepting new connections. Check out [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm) showing how to accept multiple connections.